# Searchkick number_of_fragments not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I've created the highlight feature with Searchkick and Elasticsearch in my Rails app.

Like so:

```
      def index
        @book_searches = Book.search(params[:query], operator: "or", fields: [:description], highlight: {tag: "<strong>", fields: {description: {number_of_fragments: 3, fragment_size: 100}}})
        @chapter_searches = Chapter.search(params[:query], operator: "or", fields: [:body], highlight: {tag: "<strong>", fields: {body: {number_of_fragments: 3, fragment_size: 100}}})
      end
```

Everything works well except for the **number_of_fragments** part.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

I'm looking for results similar to theses:

```
Search for "minimum wage"

Returns "a **minimum wage** rate maximum number of hours overtime pay child labor (see ... to pay a **minimum wage** and overtime to many employees, it also contains ... Pennsylvania’s **Minimum Wage** Act currently sets the minimum wage at the same rate ..."
```

It returns approximately three sentences that are separate from one another within the body of a text and (...).

Comment: What results do you get and what do you expect? Maybe sharing some sample documents would help here.

Comment: @Val I updated the post to explain what results I'm looking for.